# IOCTL() Library for Windows

Tags: linux, debian, windows, c, cross-compilation

I am trying to cross compile my c code from debian linux to a windows platform. I have worked out most of the kinks but I am struggling with ioctl().

Windows doesn't seem to have a ioctl() equivalent as I know of. Does anyone know how I could use ioctl() on windows platform?

Thanks!

Comment: In Unix, IOCTL (I/O control) is a catch-all system call to ask for random, device-dependent actions. The exact calls supported, what actions can be requested, and so on, are *extremely* operating system (and device driver) dependent. You'll probably find some "standard" ones agree between Unices, but not across the board. To Windows, just forget it. You *might* be able to use something like [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com) to run Unix source code, but I wouldn't bet on it if it uses IOCTL.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write native Windows replacement code for where you use `ioctl()`. You will need to compile and link against `Cygwin` or `MSYS(2)` runtimes. I don't know how well `ioctl()` is emulated, though.

If you go down that road, you should be aware that you can no longer cross-compile with a MinGW toolchain alone. And you will need to use wine if I'm not mistaken.

I would recommend you start experimenting with `MSYS2`. And testing your code in a **real** windows environment is a must.